# what should I use for checking inputStream other than hasNext?

Tags: java, sockets

```
while(true) {
        for(int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++) {
            System.out.println(i + " time");
            if(fromPlayer.get(i).hasNext()) {
                String command = fromPlayer.get(i).next();
                System.out.println("I Got " + command);
                executeCommand(command, i);

            }
            System.out.println("I got here.");
        }
    }
```

I am implementing a socket game. 2 players are playing, and I am using infinite while loop to check if a player entered something. The problem is that, after I checked, hasNext() from Scanner class freezes if no input's coming. If every player gets 2 chances per turn, the first player used the first chance, the if statement happens to check the second player's outputstream. But since the second player does not enter anything, the hasNext() freeze there and the first player can't do anything. 
What should I do or use other than hasNext()?

Comment: I am using thread for doing this now, but I am still waiting for an answer which is not about thread :)

Comment: You'll be waiting a long time. That *is* the answer, unless you want to delve into NIO or asynchronous sockets.